# how to send smtp email in fresh laravel 9 project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I just wanted to send mails through my gmail account
I have newly created fresh laravel 9 project guide me to send mails in easy steps

i was able to do in laravel 8 but in 9 it dosen't work like that

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should set your mail configuration in your `.env`

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mygoogle@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=rrnnucvnqlbsl
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mygoogle@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Then create mail class using this command `php artisan make:mail DemoMail`

Update your DemoMail Class to this

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Mail;
  
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
  
class DemoMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
  
    public $mailData;
  
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
    }
  
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Mail from Mansjoer@gmail.com')
                    ->view('emails.demoMail');
    }
}
```

Now create your mail controller using this command `php artisan make:controller MailController`

Put this into your MainController file

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\DemoMail;
  
class MailController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $mailData = [
            'title' => 'Mail from Mansjoer.com',
            'body' => 'This is for testing email using smtp.'
        ];
         
        Mail::to('your_email@gmail.com')->send(new DemoMail($mailData));
           
        dd("Email is sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

Create your route using this code

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MailController;

Route::get('send-mail', [MailController::class, 'index']);
```

Then make your MainController view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mansjoer Corporation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ $mailData['title'] }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $mailData['body'] }}</p>
  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     
    <p>Thank you</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can try to type the given URL and view the app output

```
http://localhost:8000/send-mail
```

Comment: If its working, dont forget to check this answer is correct. Read the rules before asking, thanks.

Comment: I got it, Thanks

Comment: No problem mate @player99